# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui.bootstrap

```
var app =  angular.module('app', ['controllers','ui.bootstrap']);
```

and I have put ui 'ui.bootstrap' file in asset\js\dependencies 
but showing the above

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

Comment: Did you import the ui.bootstrap file before injecting it into your application?

Comment: you need to follow instruction from here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Do you have a script tag with the jscript src of ui.bootstrap in your html?

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: @Gaurav We can't find bugs without seeing the code. Show us all the code and information (like where the files are) needed to prove you shouldn't have this error.